# Null Pointer Splay Tree

Tags: java, rotation, splay-tree

Im working on a right rotate method for a splay tree. I keep getting a null pointer exception when I try to run my program but im not sure why. This is my tree

```
      5
     /
    2
   /
  1
```

this is where i get the null pointer, its on the lr assignment. lr should be null because 2 doesnt have a right but shouldnt the node just be null and then the program should keep going? or since its null I have to check first if 2 will have a right?

```
    Node<E> p = findParent(x.getData());    
    Node<E> l = x.getLeft();
    Node<E> lr = l.getRight();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `l` is `null`, then `l.getRight()` will throw a null pointer exception.

You need to test whether `l` is `null`:

```
Node<E> lr = (l==null)?null:l.getRight();
```

That code will assign `null` to `lr` if `l` is `null`, and will assign `l.getRight()` if `l` is not `null`.